# Преобразование массива в объект на основе его значений Javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть массив

```
const map = ["_id", "name", "email", "balance"];
```

как можно сделать из него объект такого плана?

```
const obj = {
  id: "_id",
  name: "name",
  email: "email",
  balance: "balance" };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const map = ["_id", "name", "email", "balance"];

const obj = map.reduce((newObj, item) => {
  newObj[item] = item;
  return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: спасибо, оказывается все так просто

Comment: @СергейТокарев, формально ответ не подходит, потому что не соответствует примеру вывода у тебя в вопросе, имя ключа для `_id`  без подчеркивания в примере

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот так:

```js
let arr = ["_id", "name", "email", "balance"]
let obj = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(v => [v.replace("_",""), v]));
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: и за такой вариант спасибо

Comment: формально ответ не подходит, потому что не соответствует примеру вывода у тебя в вопросе, имя ключа для _id без подчеркивания в примере

Comment: @Grundy это да, предлагаешь заменить его на «»? :)

Comment: На что поменять? :-)

Comment: @Grundy пустой символ:)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, как вариант :) хотя автор принял ответ с таким же результатом :)

Comment: @Grundy по этой самой причине Я не стал это добавлять

Comment: @Grundy но так и не ясно автор хотел удалить все нижние подчеркивания или только первое

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, возможно только для `id`

Comment: удаление подчеркивания было не столь важно

Answer (score -2):

```js
var key = '_qqp'
var obj = {}
obj[key] = null

console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

Comment: @СергейТокарев, э, а мне, чо мне спасибо не надо? или массив перебрать не знаешь как.
допустим не знаешь, так спроси. вот так помогаешь людям, а тебе ещё и минус.

Comment: перосональное, именное спасибо в студию

Comment: спасибо и тебе, я действительно немного не понял твой вариант, но минус я не ставил

Comment: это вообще мой первый вопрос, я еще не знаю, что тут и как

Comment: @СергейТокарев, это так, сетование на русское сообщество стэк оверфлоу. или его раздела джаваскрипт. в общем велкам :)

Comment: хотя пример с  `reduce` хорош, и лично я ему плюсую